# Python global variables scope

Tags: python, scope, global-variables

Recently I caught a bug in my code which wondered me enough. The main problem is that the code below works:

```
def test():
    print(memory)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    memory = 1
    test()
```

It would be clear if `memory` were defined at the top of file but this  seems like breaking all the scope rules for me. However there must be some reason.

Comment: Seems logical to me. by the time `test()` is called, `memory` is already defined.

Comment: Python executes your program in order it reads it. When yiu define a function, it's executed only when you call it, so Python doesn't even look inside on the first run. You might as well assume that it replaces your call to 'test()' with the content of that function itself

Comment: @ifconfig Logical after what experience?  I mean I used to use C and code which uses global variable in function before declaring does not compile. And this is for me seems logical.

Comment: You meant to say illogical, right? Python has some interesting scope rules from what I can gather.

Comment: @avloss Thanks. Think I should get deeper in how python works. If you post your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @ifconfig Yes, it has. However even my code checker usually gives me an error about using variables before assignment but sometimes it just ignores all the problems(some vim bug I believe).

Comment: It isn't good practice, yes, but it just works that way..

Comment: Relevant answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/293097/4110233

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names

Comment: @avloss:  Not quite. It compiles all the code in the function `test` before `if __name__ == '__main__':`, but doesn't resolve the name referred to by `memory` until the function is called, at which point it follows scope rules for resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the working of memory variable seems strange, it is expected. The [Variable Scope](http://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html) is not breached!

**if __name__ == "__main__":** -  This statement is used for defining or declaring global functionality when the source file is called directly for execution rather than imported to another file and called from a third module.

Thus when you directly execute the source file, it will first define the variable - **memory**, to be global and can be accessed in function **test** as a global variable(*no overshadowing happening*).

Refer the below link for more understanding - [What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)